# How to get values in one column where another column equals a value with SQL, and store into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Here is my table:

```
user_id | group_id
------------------
1       | 22
2       | 22
3       | 22
4       | 1
5       | 1
```

I only want to get the user_id's from the group_id 22 and store them into an array.

My code in PHP:

```
$group_id=22;
$user_ids_ar = mysqli_fetch_array($db->query("SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE group_id=".$group_id.";"), MYSQLI_NUM);
```

It only seems to return one value instead of the expected 3. How can I solve this?

Comment: The `query()` returns a set of data and an internal pointer that indicates what the "current" row is. When you get the result back from `query()`, the pointer will be on the first row. Then when you call `mysqli_fetch_array()`, it will return the data from the row that the pointer is at (the first row) as an array. The fetch array function will also increment the pointer to the next row, so that if you call `mysqli_fetch_array()` again, it will return the second row (where the pointer has now moved to). And so on. That's why RiggsFolly's answer uses a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only getting one row returned because you are only asking for one row. You need to loop over the fetch to get them all.

```
$group_id=22;
$result = $db->query("SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE group_id=".$group_id);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM) ) {
    $user_ids_ar[] = $row;
}
```

Or you could use fetchAll in the form you were using.

```
$group_id=22;
$user_ids_ar = mysqli_fetch_all(
                                $db->query("SELECT user_id 
                                            FROM table 
                                            WHERE group_id=".$group_id)
                            , MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all` is generally the way to go for something as straight forward as this. Better performance and cleaner code.

Comment: @RToyo Not necessarily, specially if you are returning 1000's of rows in one query

Comment: That's a good point, that I should have been explicit about in my comment. I was considering the exact scenario of the OP's question, where they expect a 3 row result set.